# How to select child elements without tag from a class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made the following function to parse all child elements
from a class:

```
function getBodyHTML(data){
    var elements = "";
    var content = $(data).find(".mw-content-ltr").children();
    $(content).each(function(i, row){
        if($(row).is("h2")){        
            elements = elements.concat("<h2 class="header2">Header 2 content is: "+($(row).text())+"</h1>");
        }else if($(row).is("h1")){
            elements = elements.concat("<h1 class="header1">Header 1 content is: "+($(row).text())+"</h1>");
        }else if($(row).is("h3")){
            elements = elements.concat("<h3>"+($(row).text())+"</h3>");
        }else if($(row).is("p")){
            elements = elements.concat("<p>"+$(row).text()+"</p>");
        }

    });

        return elements;
    }
```

That function does what I want for this kind of
html:

```
<h2 class="main-header">Some Text</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, 
sed diam nonummy nibh. </p>
<p>euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat 
volutpat. Ut wisi enim</p>
<h1>Another text</h1>
<p>euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim</p>
```

But I cann't get the full text when the HTML comes this way:

```
<h2 class="main-header">Some Text</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, 
sed diam nonummy nibh.
<h1>Another text</h1>
<p>euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim</p>
```

As you can see, the first text after the **h2** has not any tag.

What condition should I add to my function to select those kind of text without tag too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: add 'else' section in your ifs

Comment: `contents()` returns all children, including text nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `contents()` instead of `children()` to get text nodes.

Text nodes have a `nodeType` of `3`.

Here are a few examples:

http://jsfiddle.net/A2Lyx/

Here's how you could change your code:

```
function getBodyHTML(data) {
    var elements = "";
    var content = $(data).find(".mw-content-ltr").contents();
    $(content).each(function (i, row) {
        if (row.nodeType == 3) {
            var text = $.trim(row.textContent);
            if (text.length > 0)
                elements = elements.concat("text content: " + text);
        else if ($(row).is("h2")) {
            elements = elements.concat("<h2 class="
            header2 ">Header 2 content is: " + ($(row).text()) + "</h1>");
        } else if ($(row).is("h1")) {
            elements = elements.concat("<h1 class="
            header1 ">Header 1 content is: " + ($(row).text()) + "</h1>");
        } else if ($(row).is("h3")) {
            elements = elements.concat("<h3>" + ($(row).text()) + "</h3>");
        } else if ($(row).is("p")) {
            elements = elements.concat("<p>" + $(row).text() + "</p>");
        }
    });

    return elements;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.contents()` method instead of `.children()` and check the `nodeType` of the node:

```
$(data).find(".mw-content-ltr").contents().each(function(_, row) {
    // ...
    } else if ( row.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(row.nodeValue).length ) {
       var textNodeValue = $.trim(row.nodeValue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add else in your if block

```
else{
   elements = elements.concat($(row).html());
}
```

Something like:

```
function getBodyHTML(data){
var elements = "";
var content = $(data).find(".mw-content-ltr").children();
$(content).each(function(i, row){
    if($(row).is("h2")){        
        elements = elements.concat("<h2 class="header2">Header 2 content is: "+($(row).text())+"</h1>");
    }else if($(row).is("h1")){
        elements = elements.concat("<h1 class="header1">Header 1 content is: "+($(row).text())+"</h1>");
    }else if($(row).is("h3")){
        elements = elements.concat("<h3>"+($(row).text())+"</h3>");
    }else if($(row).is("p")){
        elements = elements.concat("<p>"+$(row).text()+"</p>");
    }
    else{
       elements = elements.concat($(row).html());
    }

});

    return elements;
}
```