# how to get the text of an anchor that is inside a text node in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing something like this to retrieve the text content from the child nodes
of a class:

```
$(data).find(".mw-content-ltr").contents().each(function(_, row) {
    // ...
    } else if ( row.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(row.nodeValue).length ) {
       var textNodeValue = $.trim(row.nodeValue);
       console.log(textNodeValue);
    }
});
```

The problem is that if the text node has some anchors inside, like this:

```
When<a href="/wiki/Raquel_Ochmonek" title="Raquel Ochmonek"> Raquel Ochmonek</a> comes over to sit 
for <a href="/wiki/Brian_Tanner" title="Brian Tanner">Brian</a>, 
a burglar breaks into the house through the master bedroom 
where <a href="/wiki/ALF" title="ALF">ALF</a> is hiding.
```

my code won't retrieve them, resulting in something like this:

```
When

comes over to sit for

, a burglar breaks into the house through the master bedroom where

is hiding.
```

when I need something like this:

```
When  Raquel Ochmonek  comes over to sit for Brian, a burglar breaks into the house through the master bedroom where is hiding.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Text nodes cannot have `<a>` elements inside them.

Comment: thanks Pointy, so this is illegal html right? http://alf.wikia.com/wiki/Andrew_Seminick

Comment: @Boel if my understanding of the problem is correct, this is valid HTML. Pointy is saying that you won't see the `<a>` elements because you're selecting nodeType of 3 (text). `<a>` elements have a nodeType of 1.

Comment: @Boel no, it's not illegal. A text node is *only* text. When a containing element has text and inline content nodes, then the text is broken up into separate nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`$(".mw-content-ltr").text()`

Fiddle comparing the two: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/GeRVV/2/

**EDIT**: since there is other data inside the class that you aren't interested in, would something like this work?

```
$(".mw-content-ltr").contents().each(function (_, row) {
    if (row.nodeType === 3 && $.trim(row.nodeValue).length) {
        var textNodeValue = $.trim(row.nodeValue);
        console.log(textNodeValue);
    } else if (row.nodeType == 1) {
        var nodeValue = $.trim($(row).text());
        console.log(nodeValue);
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/GeRVV/5/

Comment: mmm... thanks Kyle but I can't do this because this will bring all text content inside the class, and I need to do custom things for in every node type

Comment: Can you provide more context? It's hard to know what "data" is and what else is inside that class.

Comment: yes, that class could have the next group of elements inside: text, h2, p, h3, etc... But I need to make different things depending on every node type, because of that I don't think I can use just $(".mw-content-ltr").text(). This question is related to a previous I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011581/how-to-select-child-elements-without-tag-from-a-class-in-jquery

Comment: @Boel I tidied it up a bit more, please see the new revision - it may work nicer than the switch statement :)